# how can MSIE alert 'unknow'?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, events

for some purpose i want to **cache the Window.Event object in a variable** and use it later,but MSIE keep telling me that this is 'unknow'.

just run the code below in IE,you will see what i mean

i just want to ask how can this happen?
did i miss something?

**html:**

```
<button id='btn'>Click!!!</button>
```

**JS:**

```
    var eventObj = null;
    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
       eventObj = window.event;
       setTimeout(function() {
          alert(typeof eventObj.srcElement);
       }, 1000)
    }​
```

**EIDT 1:**

i have search some test done by other ,see the below:

**HTML :**

```
<button id='btn1'>Click 1 !!</button>
<button id="btn2">Click 2 !!</button>
```

**JS**

```
var btn1EventObj = null;
document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function() {
    btn1EventObj = window.event;
    alert(btn1EventObj.srcElement.id);
}
document.getElementById('btn2').onclick = function() {
    alert(btn1EventObj === window.event); // output:false;
    alert(btn1EventObj.srcElement === window.event.srcElement); // output: true ; 
    alert(btn1EventObj.srcElement.id); // output: btn2 ;
}
```

when the btn1 has been click i assume i cache the 'event object' in the **btn1EventObj**,and then click the btn2:

test:

**btn1EventObj === window.event -> false;** // there is not only one event object in MSIE

**btn1EventObj.srcElement === window.event.srcElement -> true** // i can not understand this one the the below.

**btn1EventObj.srcElement.id ->btn2**

see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/strangeline/3tFwj/1/)

so all the above tell me that maybe all the event raised in MSIE are all share attributes ,and when the btn2 is clicked,all the previous attribute are overwrite by the later one?

am i kind of right ?

Comment: And here is a fiddle of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/jdkJT/

Comment: Do you really think writing IE-only code is a good idea?!

Comment: @ThiefMaster Nope, somehow as a developer i just a little bit hate IE,but the above should be a problem that i want to solve and understand the reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't copy `window.event` out of context of the actual event in IE. In other words: there is no existing event when you assign the handler in the script. If you want to refer to the `window.event`, the handler has to be assigned inline.

MSDN:

```
The event object is available only during an event—that is,
you can use it in event handlers but not in other code.
```

HTML:

```
<button id='btn' onclick="clicker(event);">Click!!!</button>
```

and JS:

```
function clicker(e){
    setTimeout(function (){
        alert(e.srcElement);
    },1000);
    return;
}
```

[`event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: thanks! i see you point! so i can only cache the Event.target but not the event itself, right?

Comment: @strangeline That's how I have understood `event` in IE.

Comment: No need to pass an event for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

the `window.event' is a global object and may be changed on each event that raised. many events raised on browser within miliseconds.

NOTE:

**if you set `var y = someObject` the object was not copied into `y` variable, the `y` variable just contains the address of the object in memory(you can google about: object reference and pointers ).so you need to copy object into `y` , or try alternative solution below:**

so you need to use `function(e){}` style event handlers:

```
var eventObj = null; 
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(e) { 
   eventObj = e;
   setTimeout(function() { 
      alert(typeof eventObj.srcElement); 
   }, 1000) 
}
```

see this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdkJT/9/)

EDIT 1:

in M$ IE you can use this code:

```
function copyObject(o){
    return {srcElement: o.srcElement,
           ...
           more attributes ...
            };
}

var eventObj = null; 
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(e) { 
   eventObj = copyObject(window.event);
   setTimeout(function() { 
      alert(typeof eventObj.srcElement); 
   }, 1000) 
}
```

see on [jsfiddle(Edited)](http://jsfiddle.net/jdkJT/11/)

Comment: In IE, the event object is not passed to the event listener, but a global `window.event` instead.

Comment: After applying that change, what's the difference versus the original code?

Comment: see edits. on jsfiddle and please test it on ie. i dont have ie.

Comment: I'd suggest that the use of 'M$' cheapens your answer a little, but it's a personal thing.

Comment: yas , but i spend approx 2 hours per day , to find solutions of M$ bugs

Answer (score 0):

```
var eventObj = null;
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
   eventObj = window.event;
   setTimeout((function(eventObj) {
      alert(typeof eventObj.srcElement);
   })(eventObj), 1000)
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/4nHmz/1/)

The event object is available only during an event-that is, you can use it in event handlers but not in other code and you are using `setTimeout` so it's not available after the event has been executed because to avoid conflict IE set it to null and after 1 second it's not available, so you can use a closure.

Comment: This code runs the anonymous function inside `setTimeout` instantly, also it throws `Bad argument` error.